# how to use mapreduce with hadoop

Tags: hadoop

im trying to implement an algorithm to find connected components in a large graph(size equivalent to social networks) using Mapreduce. Im not familiar with Hadoop though ive heard it can be used. I need some direction with using it.

Comment: i need to run a simulation of a distributed ssystem..not an actual distributed system.

Comment: It depends how your graph is stored. Is it a giant data structure serialized to a file? Or it has vertices stored at each line? Answer to this question will put us on the right track to get to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/index.html). It is Hadoop-based framework to work with graph algorithms.